# How to change filter "and" to "or"?

Tags: module, magento2.4, products, filter, query

**version : Magento 2.4 safira**
I want my website show every products related to filters I choose.
If I choose multi filters, I only got products fulfilled all conditions.
Is there any way I can edit this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite the filter functionality OR condition like this:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute' => 'someattribute', 'like' => 'value'),
        array('attribute' => 'otherattribute', 'like' => 'value'),
        array('attribute' => 'anotherattribute', 'like' => 'value'),
    )
);
```

Hope, it will help you.